# Trees and a LinkPane, as markup

Tags: tree, dojo

Couldn't find an answer to this but perhaps some knows the answer.

Using DOJO 1.10, and I have a LinkPane that loads mark up for a Tree returned. It's set to parse on load.

Anyway the data is stored in the model. Model.store.data has an array of elements in it, but when it renders it only displays the root node. I can't expand it. Event when autoExpand is set to true. Ideas?

```
<div data-dojo-id="queryStore" data-dojo-type="dojo/store/Memory">
<script 
    type="dojo/method">  
    this.setData([ { "id": "queryRoot", "name": "Queries"}, ... ]);
</script>
<script 
    data-dojo-event="getChildren"
    data-dojo-args="object"
    type="dojo/method">
    return this.query({parent: object.id}); 
</script>
</div>  
<div data-dojo-id="queryModel"
     data-dojo-type="dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel"
     data-dojo-props="store: queryStore, query: {id:'queryRoot'}"/>
<div id="queriesTree" 
     data-dojo-props="model:queryModel,autoExpand:true" 
     data-dojo-type="dijit/Tree"/>
```

Comment: Can you please try to publish some of the code and parameters?

Comment: Here's some code:  <div data-dojo-id="queryStore" data-dojo-type="dojo/store/Memory">
 <script type="dojo/method">
  this.setData([
   { "id": "queryRoot", "name": "Queries"},
   ...
   ]);
 </script>
 <script data-dojo-event="getChildren" data-dojo-args="object" type="dojo/method">
  return this.query({parent: object.id});
 </script>
</div>
<div data-dojo-id="queryModel" data-dojo-type="dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel" data-dojo-props="store: queryStore, query: {id:'queryRoot'}"/>
<div id="queriesTree" data-dojo-props="model:queryModel,autoExpand:true" data-dojo-type="dijit/Tree"/>

Comment: It is placed in the model.store.data  But on render it only does the root node event with an autoExpand: true... the code is returned to the LinkPane which is set to parseOnLoad

Comment: Thanks Dan - can you please insert the code into the question (edit mode) thanks. Indent 4 characters to make sure it is shown as code.

Comment: Done. Sorry guys, new to posting.

Comment: I have edited and spaced it out for you, can you check please that I haven't made any errors.  Ps - I had to remove an extra `>` from the script and put and extra `<` to mark one of your divs

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  Of course the ,... in the JSON is indicative that there is more, and I didn't have space.

Comment: Found the problem! I forgot the parent property! D'oh!

Comment: Cool - if you write up the answer other people might benefit, and also you might get your answer or question marked higher and get some points :)